# How to overload generic methods in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript has an overload function that changes the signature of the method depending on the type of the argument. However, since TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, only one implementation can be created, so it is necessary to branch internally by looking at the value.

On the other hand, in some cases, it is not possible to sort internally because the difference in type is only the difference in generics...

**lib.es5.d.ts**

```
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  // Abbreviation
  filter<S extends T>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];
  filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[];
  // Abbreviation
}
```

In the case of `Array.prototype.filter`, the type is switched when the callback is a function of `value is S`.　However, if you actually define `filter (callback)` after declaring such an interface, it will be full of type errors, such as `callback 'implicitly has an' any 'type'`. However, like Java, generics disappear at compile time, so dynamic branching is not possible.

You can write anyway by "Strictly defining the type internally, using any or as to suppress type errors".
However, is there any way to implement such a method overload that differs only in generics, except for ignoring the type at the time of implementation?

Comment: Can you show what exactly function you want to do?

Comment: "If you actually define..." maybe you can provide a [mcve] so others can see exactly what you're talking about?  Overloads have a single implementation, which need to work for all call signatures.  When you implement `filter()` (presuming I guess that you're writing your own implementation of `Array`, and if so, why?  What's wrong with the existing `Array` implementation?) you'll need to give it a real signature, such as `filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[] { return this.arr.filter(callbackfn);  }`.